# Python evaluation order

Tags: python

Here's the code, I don't quite understand, how does it work. Could anyone tell, is that an expected behavior?

```
$ipython

In [1]: 1 in [1] == True
Out[1]: False

In [2]: (1 in [1]) == True
Out[2]: True

In [3]: 1 in ([1] == True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/dmedvinsky/projects/condo/condo/<ipython console> in <module>()

TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

In [4]: from sys import version_info

In [5]: version_info
Out[5]: (2, 6, 4, 'final', 0)
```

Comment: -1: This is completely and trivially covered in the Python documentation.  http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary.  This doesn't seem to be a "question"; it seems to be an actual refusal to read the Python documentation.

Comment: Actually, this threw me when I read it.  It's Python comparison chaining, but with an unusual pair of operators.  S.Lott: don't be so quick to condemn questions.  Python comparison chaining is an unusual feature of the language, and this is an unusual application of chaining.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an example of "chaining" which is a gotcha in Python.  It's a (possibly silly) trick of Python that:

```
a op b op c
```

is equivalent to:

```
(a op b) and (b op c)
```

for all operators of the same precedence.  Unfortunately, `in` and `==` have the same precedence, as do `is` and all comparisons.

So, here is your unexpected case:

```
1 in [1] == True  # -> (1 in [1]) and ([1] == True) -> True and False -> False
```

See See http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#summary for the precedence table.

Comment: Chaining is often used for expressions like `1 < x < 5` (so it's not always silly), but in that case I was quite surprised too. Good exploration Charles!

Comment: True, though I wish `1 < 5 > 2 < 3 in range(4) == [0, 1, 2, 3]` did not chain.

Comment: Chaining is good, not a gotcha. Relying on guessed or incorrectly deduced operator precedence is bad in any language -- if it's anything out of the ordinary * + and or etc bracket, use parentheses!

Comment: No.  If anything is out of the ordinary such that it is likely an error would likely occur, the language should optimize programmer time and flag it.

Comment: Just to clarify, chaining only happens on comparison operators, not on "all operators of the same precedence." Though, it is true that comparison operators do have the same precedence.