# How does interval comparison work?

Tags: python, syntax, comparison

Somehow, this works:

```
def in_range(min, test, max):
    return min <= test <= max

print in_range(0, 5, 10)  # True
print in_range(0, 15, 10)  # False
```

However, I can't quite figure out the order of operations here. Let's test the `False` case:

```
print 0 <= 15 <= 10  # False
print (0 <= 15) <= 10  # True
print 0 <= (15 <= 10)  # True
```

Clearly, this isn't resolving to a simple order of operations issue. Is the interval comparison a special operator, or is something else going on?

Comment: related-but-not-quite-duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452837/python-evaluation-order

Comment: `print (0 <= 15) <= 10 ` evaluates to `True`. But It makes no sense to ask `True <= 10`, even if it is defined by Python. I think in these cases it is best to think "Pythonic"; what is the concept that we are trying to do here? A: We do indeed get the interval comparison as desired.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Unlike most languages, Python supports [chained comparison operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comp_operator) and it evaluates them as they would be evaluated in normal mathematics.

This line:

```
return min <= test <= max
```

is evaluated by Python like this:

```
return (min <= test) and (test <= max)
```

Most other languages however would evaluate it like this:

```
return (min <= test) <= max
```

Comment: you can even do crazier stuff like `a < b <= c < d <= e` ... although it starts getting really confusing once you go more than 2 comparisons

Comment: So the comparison operations are evalueted left to right, i.e. if `min <= test` evaluates to `False`, `test <= max` is not evaluated? But I guess that in `min <= test <= max`, `test` is always evaluated only once, while in the expression `(min <= test) and (test <= max)`, `test` may be evaluated one or two times (depending on the value of `min <= test`)?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye good question. In `min <= test() <= max` the `test()` function will only be evaluated once.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Or even crazier, `a==b==c==0` or `a==b==c!=0` (all same non-zero value) or `0<a==b==c` (all same positive value) or `0<a<=9>=b>0<c<=9` (a, b, c are 1-9). Any number of any compare operations.

Answer (score 5):

As specified in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).
>
> Formally, if *a*, *b*, *c*, ..., *y*, *z* are expressions and *op1*, *op2*, ..., *opN* are comparison operators, then `a op1 b op2 c ... y opN z` is equivalent to `a op1 b and b op2 c and ... y opN z`, except that each expression is evaluated at most once.