# Grade calculator range and ValueError - Python

Tags: python

I'm new to python and have been trying to create a simple grade calculator which tells the user what grade they've achieved based on their final score they've inputted.

```
def grades():
try:
    score = int(input("Please enter your score between 0 and 100:"))
    if score >= 90:
        print("Grade:A")
    elif score >= 80 :
        print("Grade:B")
    elif score >= 70:
        print("Grade:C")
    elif score >= 60:
        print("Grade:D")
    elif score >= 50:
        print("Grade:E")
    elif score < 50:
        print("Grade:F")
except score not in range (0,101) or ValueError:
    int(input("Incorrect value. Please enter your score between 0 and 100:"))
```

However when I try to run the program, it disregards the range and value error and gives it a grade anyway. Is there any way to rectify this, and if possible how could I make the program more efficient. As I said, I'm new to python, so any feedback would be useful.

Comment: I tried to address some points of efficiency in my answer. `try/except` is an expensive function, plus you're not using it correctly, so I've avoided it. `score < 50` is redundant after you've checked other values, so I avoid doing so. Typing "Grade:x" many times isn't necessary when all you want to change is the letter, so I've addressed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, let's make it a Match Case statement:

Since you only accept integers, we can take and assign score to input with `:=`, then check if it's valid with `str.isnumeric`. If that's true then we'll make `score` an integer `:=` and check if it's between 0 and 100.

We'll change the input statement if they don't put valid input the first time around.

```
def grades():
    text = "Please enter your score between 0 and 100: "
    while True:
        if ((score := input(text)).isnumeric() and
            (score := int(score)) in range(0, 101)):
            break
        else:
            text = "Incorrect value. Please enter your score between 0 and 100: "
    match score:
        case x if x >= 90 : grade = 'A'
        case x if x >= 80 : grade = 'B'
        case x if x >= 70 : grade = 'C'
        case x if x >= 60 : grade = 'D'
        case x if x >= 50 : grade = 'E'
        case _ : grade = 'F'
    print(f'Grade: {grade}')
```

Please note that this will only work in `Python 3.10` or greater.

Answer (score 0):

I made some corrections to your code. I added some comments to help explain what is going on. Let me know if this solution works for you:

```py
def grades():
    while True:
        # Start a loop to ask for user input:
        score = int(input("Please enter your score between 0 and 100:"))
        # If not in range 1, 100, print error message
        if score in range(0, 101):
            break
        print('Incorrect value. Please enter your score between 0 and 100:')
         

    # calculate grade:
    if score >= 90:
        print("Grade:A")
    elif score >= 80:
        print("Grade:B")
    elif score >= 70:
        print("Grade:C")
    elif score >= 60:
        print("Grade:D")
    elif score >= 50:
        print("Grade:E")
    elif score < 50:
        print("Grade:F")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    grades()
```

Comment: `continue` does nothing in that code block

Comment: the keyword `continue` causes execution to skip to the next iteration. the same effect can be achieved without invoking the keyword at all. it makes the code more complicated without adding an effect. I ran the code to confirm what I know, and I was correct.

Comment: I stand corrected. You are indeed correct!

Answer (score 0):

> I have made changes to your code, please test to ensure it performs to expectations.

1. I have added a `while True` loop, which attempts to validate the score to be between `0 - 100`. If a non-integer value is entered it will hit the `ValueError` exception. This loop will only exit when a number within the range is entered.
2. The `if` statements use interval comparators `X <= score < Y`. You can read more about interval comparators [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436150/how-does-interval-comparison-work).
3. The `if` statement was also removed out of the `try - except` to make debugging easier. The idea is to have the least code possible in `try - except` so that when an exception triggers, it would be caused by the intended code.
4. Lastly, you don't want to ask for the user input inside the `exception` as the user might enter something which may cause another exception which will go uncaught.

```py
def grades():
    while True:

        # Perform basic input validation.
        try:

            # Gets the user input.
            score = int(input("Please enter your score between 0 and 100: "))

            # Checks if the number entered is within 0 - 100. Note that range is non-inclusive for the stop. If it is within 0 - 100 break out of the while loop.
            if 0 <= score <= 100:
                break

        # If a non-integer is entered an exception will be thrown.
        except ValueError:
            print("Input entered is not a valid number")

    # Checking of scores using interval comparison
    if score >= 90:
        print("Grade:A")
    elif 80 <= score < 90:
        print("Grade:B")
    elif 70 <= score < 80:
        print("Grade:C")
    elif 60 <= score < 70:
        print("Grade:D")
    elif 50 <= score < 60:
        print("Grade:E")
    else:
        print("Grade:F")
```

Comment: Why don't you just use comparison operators instead of calling the `range()` function? Furthermore, if you're already verifying that `score` is in the closed interval `[0, 100]`, there's no need to check again in the conditional statements that follow (i.e., `< 101` and `0 <=` are superfluous).

Comment: @JacobLee, after some thought I have adjusted my code accordingly, thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
def grades():
    try:
        score = int(input("Please enter your score between 0 and 100:"))
        if score > 100:
            while True:
                int(input("Incorrect value. Please enter your score between 0 and 100:"))
                if score <= 100:
                    pass
                else:
                    break
        if score >= 90:
            print("Grade:A")
        elif score >= 80 :
            print("Grade:B")
        elif score >= 70:
            print("Grade:C")
        elif score >= 60:
            print("Grade:D")
        elif score >= 50:
            print("Grade:E")
        elif score < 50:
            print("Grade:F")
    except:
        print("Oops. sommthing went wrong")

grades();
```

Comment: "PEP 8 rightly advises against the use of a bare ‘except’. While it is syntactically legal in a statement, and for backward compatibility must remain so, there is little value in encouraging its use." [Source](https://peps.python.org/pep-0463/#bare-except-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

Simply assert that the input is in the determined range before checking through score ranges. Really, there is no need for a `try`/`except` statement.

```py
def grades():
    while True:
        score = int(input(...))
        if 0 <= score <= 100:
            break
        # Invalid score
    # Check score ranges
    ...
```